# Conditionally trigger Animated.timing from ScrollY position of ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I've created a template for screens throughout my app. The template utilises Animated Header components that respond to the scrollY position of the ScrollView content.

I'm able to use this scrollY variable to interpolate items, but I can't figure out how to use the variable to trigger `Animated.timing` events.

In simple terms:

- `if (ScrollY > 30)` do Animated.timing one
- `if (ScrollY < 30)` do Animated.timing two

For now I've created an inadequate workaround using the `Animated.event() listener`:

```
<ScrollView
onScroll={Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollListener } } }],
  {
    listener: (event) => {
      handleScroll(event);
    },
  }
)}
 ...
```

The `handleScroll(event)` controls an array of `Animated.timing` events, each of which operates conditionally from a `setScrollPosition()` `useState` variable:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
const fixedHeaderTranslatePosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(4)).current;

const handleScroll = (event) => {

setScrollPosition(
  event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y +
    (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT : 0)
);

if (scrollPosition > 30 && headerType === 'Animated') {
  Animated.timing(fixedHeaderTranslatePosition, {
    toValue: 0,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start();

...

}
```

Whilst my efforts do create a functional component, there are some minor problems.
Firstly, the `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` seems to cause a lag on Android devices. This is most noticeable with the `fixedHeaderTranslatePosition`.

Also logically it would make much more sense to utilise the already declared `scrollListener` from the `Animated.event`. So my question is: How can I utilise the `ScrollY` variable (`scrollListener`) inside my `handleScroll()`?

The `ScrollY` variable is not noted above since it makes more sense in context. Here's a working snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@dazzerr/animated-header-example . You can search for "TODO" to find the areas that I believe require attention.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found any solutions ?